# How to rearrange a multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array that's in the following format:

```
Array
(
    [Jan 14] => Array
        (
            [wasteHierarchy] => Recycling
            [completionDate] => Jan 14
            [totalUom] => 102854
        )

    [Feb 14] => Array
        (
            [wasteHierarchy] => Recycling
            [completionDate] => Feb 14
            [totalUom] => 83954
        )
    [Mar 14] => Array
        (
            [wasteHierarchy] => Landfill
            [completionDate] => Mar 14
            [totalUom] => 97506
        )
)
```

However I need to change the way the array is laid out. I want to create an array that is in this format:

```
Array
(
    [Recycling] => Array
        (
            [Jan 14] => 102854
            [Feb 14] => 83954
        )
    [Landfill] => Array
        (
            [Mar 14] => 97506
        )
)
```

This is the code I have at the moment:

```
    $whmOutput = Array();
    foreach($wasteHierMonArr as $whm) {
        $dateChanged = date("M y", strtotime($whm['completion_date']));

        $whmOutput_element = &$whmOutput[$dateChanged];
        $whmOutput_element['wasteHierarchy'] = $whm['waste_hierarchy'];
        $whmOutput_element['completionDate'] = $dateChanged;
        !isset($whmOutput_element['totalUom']) && $whmOutput_element['totalUom'] = 0;
        $whmOutput_element['totalUom'] += $whm['totalTonne'];
    }

    $newWHM = array();
    foreach($whmOutput as $whm) {
        $dateChanged = $whm['completionDate'];

        $wasteHierarchy = $whm['wasteHierarchy'];
        $totalUom = +$whm['totalUom'];

        $newWHM[$wasteHierarchy][$dateChanged] = $totalUom;
    }
```

However, this only returns one array:

```
Array
(
    [Recycling] => Array
        (
            [Jan 14] => 102854
            [Feb 14] => 83954
        )
)
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**
`$wasteHierMonArr` is generated from an SQL statement:

```
SELECT SUM(total_uom) AS totalTonne, waste_hierarchy, completion_date 
FROM enviro_figures_upload 
WHERE completion_date != '' 
AND waste_hierarchy != '' 
GROUP BY waste_hierarchy, DATE_FORMAT(completion_date, '%m-%Y') DESC 
ORDER BY YEAR(completion_date) ASC, MONTH(completion_date) ASC, waste_hierarchy ASC
```

Comment: Assuming that `$whmOutput` is what you say it is, your code (second part) should work just fine.

Comment: The outputs are direct from the app using the above code, so all outputs are real. `$wasteHierMonArr` is generated from an SQL Query, would that cause an issue?

Comment: I would suggest, for the benefit of others trying to help you, to create a script that reproduces your issue; i.e. create a fiddle, 3v4l, codepad, whatever.

Comment: Lol take your pick - 3 identical answers posted w/in 40 seconds of each other. Must be the right one :)

Comment: None of them worked. If put in the same foreach as they described no results are returned. If I put the code inside the `$whmOutput` loop it returns the same results as I was getting.

Comment: I didn't down vote anyone? This is in a Symfony2 application and I'm suspecting it's the framework that's having issues at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
foreach($wasteHierMonArr as $datekey => $dta){
    $newWHM[$dta['wasteHierarchy']][$datekey] = $dta['totalUom];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$whmOutput = Array();
foreach ($wasteHierMonArr as $whm) {
    $whmOutput[$whm['wasteHeirarchy']][$whm['completionDate']] = $whm['totalUom'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = [];
foreach ($wasteHierMonArr as $data) {
    $result[$data['wasteHierarchy']][$data['completionDate']] = $data['totalUom'];
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: This didn't return any results in the `$wasteHierMonArr` loop, I moved it to the `$whmOutput` loop and it returns the same results as I was getting before.